# Failed to load FileDescriptorProto for '_CLOUD_QUERY_METADATA_SCHEMA_'

Tags: google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

My Firebase project is integrated with BigQuery, so all raw Google Analytics events are exported daily & streamed to a dedicated collection.

Since today even simple queries on those events are failing with an error:

> **Error running query**
>
> Failed to load FileDescriptorProto for
> '*CLOUD_QUERY_METADATA_SCHEMA*': ;Field number 23 has already been
> used in "Msg_0_CLOUD_QUERY_TABLE" by field "items".

An example query which is failing:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `project.analytics_184030700.events_*` WHERE event_name IN ("share")
```

As I mentioned, those (and more advanced) queries used to run until yesterday. I did not change the schema nor any other configuration in the meantime. I've also noticed that [BigQuery was updated yesterday](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/release-notes).

Looking at the error description, looks like my table schema indeed contains a field called `items` (a very last one, 23rd) but it was automatically added by Google Analytics.

**My suspicions:**

1. Something went wrong with the recent BigQuery release
2. Something went wrong during daily sync Google Analytics -> BigQuery
3. Some old job or cache is getting in the way of new queries

At this point I have no idea what to try next. Does anyone have any insight into what could be causing this error?

**EDIT:**
I noticed that this problem was also just reported in the Google Issue Tracker here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/192325507.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it's a new BigQuery bug (it's me who reported https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/192325507). In the meantime, please note that you can work it around by querying for specific fields by name without the wildcard.

Answer (score 3):

I have same issue and I didn't solve it yet but as you said it's cause is Firebase I guess. There's an extra field problem which are limited only for three days (26th,27th and 28th June).

[image: privacy_info problem firebase bigquery]

I checked all data older than 26th June but there was no privacy_info field. As you see there is no privacy_info field again for 29th June. I think firebase put this new field but they changed their mind for some reason. But this causes a big problem for us.

Update:
I changed this part:

```
SELECT * FROM `project.analytics_184030700.events_*`
```

Like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `project.analytics_184030700.events_2*`
```

Interestingly this worked for me.

Comment: I just noticed that this problem was also reported in the Google Issue Tracker here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/192325507.

Comment: I updated my comment above, check last part.

Comment: @VolkanEgeDindar I think your example which works above will just have filtered the problem dates from your query, but this isn't really a solution as it just means you are missing data (you will only look at tables that start with a _2 prefix) ?

Comment: @ChrisBarry It doesn't include intraday data. But works with every other even they have privacy_info field or not. Every event table already starts with 'events_2' except intraday, I just excluded it. If you still need intraday in your data this solution will not work for you.

Comment: @ChrisBarry Also I found out we still can't UNION 25th and 26th June event data because of column count difference. So how does 'events_2*' work I don't know.

Comment: @VolkanEgeDindar looks like your workaround indeed worked in my case, thank you!

Comment: Yeah, I'm unioning a bunch of stuff together, and this blows it out and breaks everything...

Answer (score 0):

You can do a workaround for that issue; It seems there are problems with the field

privacy_info

If you select multiple table partitions, just make sure you **only select the fields you need**, and omit the field privacy_info.

Not using "SELECT *" did resolve this error for me.